# Reloading the Pre-Render Preview in After Effects Using ExtendScript

Tags: plugins, adobe, jsx, extendscript, after-effects

I'm developing an ExtendScript CEP Panel for After Effects that makes changes to the individual frames of a layer's *source video file* through an external Python script. After changes are made to the source file, After Effects often does not correctly display the updates made and instead appears to be relying on the *Memory and Disk Cache* for pre-render previewing purposes. As more edits are made over the course of a few minutes, the preview eventually refreshes to display the changes, however this is not ideal for our editing purposes.

To resolve this issue programatically, I have tried two approaches:

1. The menu bar in the After Effects application itself features an option to *"Purge > All Memory & Disk Cache..."* which deletes all cached media and refreshes the preview instantly. While I did find a way to execute this menu option programatically using an ExtendScript function `app.executeCommand(10200)`, the approach prompts the user to confirm the purge in a dialogue box and seems too computationally expensive to execute on each frame of a processed video.
2. Another approach I tried was programatically reloading the media using `layer.source.mainSource.reload()`, however this did not seem to resolve the issue either.

Is it possible to reliably refresh the main pre-render preview in After Effects programatically with ExtendScript to reflect changes in source media?